# Write the quadratic polynomial in the form $A(x+b)^2 + C$

Tags: polynomials

I am going through a textbook and had to factorise the expression below which I did. The next question wants me to write it in the form $A(x+ B)^2 + C$.

The back of the textbook just gave the answer as the factorised form $x(x+3)(x-7)$.

$x^3 -4x^2 -21x$

Comment: Assuming $A,B,C$ are all constants, there is absolutely no way to factor $x^3-4x^2-21x$ into the form $A(x+B)^2+C$ since the polynomial on the left is degree three but the polynomial on the right is degree two.  Perhaps you are asking to factor $x^2-4x-21$ into the form $A(x+B)^2+C$ instead using a technique called "[completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)"

Comment: If $A,B,C$ are constants it is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, it must be an error in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to keep simplifying. Starting with

$$
f(x) = x^{3} - 4x^{2} - 21 x
$$

---

Pull out the overall $x$ factor:

$$
 f(x) = x \underbrace{\left( x^{2} - 4x - 21\right)}_{quadratic}
$$

---

At this point in the curriculum, you are an expert at quadratics. The constant term in the quadratic has only one prime factorization:
$$
 21 = \boxed{7} \times \boxed{3}
$$
The quadratic term factors as 
$$
x^{2} - 4x - 21 = \left( x - \boxed{7} \right) \left( x + \boxed{3} \right)
$$

---

This agrees with the posted solution:
$$
 f(x) = x^{3} - 4x^{2} - 21 x = x \left( x - 7 \right) \left( x + 3 \right)
$$

---

Note: the given form $a(x+b)^{2}+c$ is quadratic. The stated problem is cubic. $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$